# how to get substring in Android?

Tags: android, string, file, substring

I am  trying to get last subString from String, As I have a file name tulips.jpg how can I get only .jpg using substring method?

I have used:

```
String Main_String =  dsfdsf.jpg or dfdfgfhfghgh.jpg or dsfsdfgdgsdg.jpg; 

(can have any length, not fixed length)

String str_jpg = Main_String.substring(1, Main_String.length());
```

/////////////////////

```
for(int i=0; i < folderResponse.getPropertyCount(); i++) 
        {
            SoapObject SingleFolder = (SoapObject)folderResponse.getProperty(i);

        ID = Integer.parseInt(SingleFolder.getProperty(0).toString());
        KEY_SUBFOLDERNAME = SingleFolder.getProperty(1).toString();
        KEY_SUBJECTTYPE = SingleFolder.getProperty(3).toString();

            String[] str = KEY_SUBFOLDERNAME.split(".");
            for(int j = 0; j < str.length; j++){
                  System.out.println(""+str[j]);
                  // you got all name here use what ever you want.
                  if(str[1] == "jpg"){
                        FolderList item = new FolderList(JPGimages[0], SingleFolder.getProperty(1).toString();, SingleFolder.getProperty(3).toString();;
                        Subfolderdata.add(item);
                    }
```

Please suggest now

Thanks

```
     03-01 16:28:17.115: I/FolderID(3254): 13002
03-01 16:28:17.115: I/User_ID(3254): 1
03-01 16:28:17.175: D/dalvikvm(3254): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 16K, 5% free 7881K/8263K, paused 52ms
03-01 16:28:17.175: I/dalvikvm-heap(3254): Grow heap (frag case) to 8.042MB for 262160-byte allocation
03-01 16:28:17.255: D/dalvikvm(3254): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 6% free 8134K/8583K, paused 70ms
03-01 16:28:17.705: I/AllFolders(3254): anyType{FileFolderDetails=anyType{ID=13003; Name=Doc file; URL=anyType{}; SubjectType=Folder; }; FileFolderDetails=anyType{ID=13004; Name=My Pics; URL=anyType{}; SubjectType=Folder; }; FileFolderDetails=anyType{ID=13005; Name=Testing; URL=anyType{}; SubjectType=Folder; }; FileFolderDetails=anyType{ID=13075; Name=satnam; URL=anyType{}; SubjectType=Folder; }; FileFolderDetails=anyType{ID=13080; Name=Saini; URL=anyType{}; SubjectType=Folder; }; FileFolderDetails=anyType{ID=13084; Name=Jelly; URL=anyType{}; SubjectType=Folder; }; FileFolderDetails=anyType{ID=13092; Name=pushie; URL=anyType{}; SubjectType=Folder; }; FileFolderDetails=anyType{ID=13096; Name=Jarnail_Testing; URL=anyType{}; SubjectType=Folder; }; FileFolderDetails=anyType{ID=13099; Name=amarjeet; URL=anyType{}; SubjectType=Folder; }; FileFolderDetails=anyType{ID=13101; Name=Kuta; URL=anyType{}; SubjectType=Folder; }; FileFolderDetails=anyType{ID=13103; Name=tajmehal; URL=anyType{}; SubjectType=Folder; }; FileFolderDetails=anyType{ID=13105; Name=TextArea; URL=anyType{}; SubjectType=Folder; }; FileFolderDetails=anyType{ID=13107; Name=TextArea1; URL=anyType{}; SubjectType=Folder; }; FileFolderDetails=anyType{ID=13109; Name=TextArea2; URL=anyType{}; SubjectType=Folder; }; FileFolderDetails=anyType{ID=13115; Name=TextArea3; URL=anyType{}; SubjectType=Folder; }; FileFolderDetails=anyType{ID=13121; Name=TextArea5; URL=anyType{}; SubjectType=Folder; }; FileFolderDetails=anyType{ID=13124; Name=Check Char; URL=anyType{}; SubjectType=Folder; }; FileFolderDetails=anyType{ID=13128; Name=amitestinggggg; URL=anyType{}; SubjectType=Folder; }; FileFolderDetails=anyType{ID=13132; Name=kkk; URL=anyType{}; SubjectType=Folder; }; FileFolderDetails=anyType{ID=13136; Name=hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh; URL=anyType{}; SubjectType=Folder; }; FileFolderDetails=anyType{ID=13140; Name=ravitevffvvgfdcvgbgvf; URL=anyType{}; SubjectType=Folder; }; FileFolderDetails=anyType{ID=13002; Name=Capture.PNG; URL=Tulips.jpg; SubjectType=File; }; FileFolderDetails=anyType{ID=13002; Name=Capture1.PNG; URL=Tulips.jpg; SubjectType=File; }; FileFolderDetails=anyType{ID=13002; Name=Chrysanthemum.jpg; URL=Tulips.jpg; SubjectType=File; }; FileFolderDetails=anyType{ID=13002; Name=Content4Work.pdf; URL=Tulips.jpg; SubjectType=File; }; FileFolderDetails=anyType{ID=13002; Name=Desert.jpg; URL=Tulips.jpg; SubjectType=File; }; FileFolderDetails=anyType{ID=13002; Name=DMS_Drag_and_Drop(2).doc; URL=Tulips.jpg; SubjectType=File; }; FileFolderDetails=anyType{ID=13002; Name=groups.jpg; URL=Tulips.jpg; SubjectType=File; }; FileFolderDetails=anyType{ID=13002; Name=Jellyfish.jpg; URL=Tulips.jpg; SubjectType=File; }; FileFolderDetails=anyType{ID=13002; Name=Koala.jpg; URL=Tulips.jpg; SubjectType=File; }; FileFolderDetails=anyType{ID=13002; Name=Lighthouse.jpg; URL=Tulips.jpg; SubjectType=File; }; FileFolderDetails=anyType{ID=13002; Name=office.jpg; URL=Tulips.jpg; SubjectType=File; }; FileFolderDetails=anyType{ID=13002; Name=Penguins.jpg; URL=Tulips.jpg; SubjectType=File; }; FileFolderDetails=anyType{ID=13002; Name=Rohit.docx; URL=Tulips.jpg; SubjectType=File; }; FileFolderDetails=anyType{ID=13002; Name=Tulips.jpg; URL=Tulips.jpg; SubjectType=File; }; }
03-01 16:28:17.725: W/System.err(3254): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=1
03-01 16:28:17.725: W/System.err(3254):     at com.web.dms.Files_Folders_Activity.subfolderTreedata(Files_Folders_Activity.java:106)
03-01 16:28:17.725: W/System.err(3254):     at com.web.dms.Files_Folders_Activity.onCreate(Files_Folders_Activity.java:56)
03-01 16:28:17.735: W/System.err(3254):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
03-01 16:28:17.735: W/System.err(3254):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
03-01 16:28:17.735: W/System.err(3254):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
03-01 16:28:17.735: W/System.err(3254):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
03-01 16:28:17.735: W/System.err(3254):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
03-01 16:28:17.735: W/System.err(3254):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
03-01 16:28:17.735: W/System.err(3254):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-01 16:28:17.735: W/System.err(3254):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-01 16:28:17.745: W/System.err(3254):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
03-01 16:28:17.745: W/System.err(3254):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-01 16:28:17.745: W/System.err(3254):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-01 16:28:17.745: W/System.err(3254):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-01 16:28:17.755: W/System.err(3254):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-01 16:28:17.779: W/System.err(3254):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-01 16:30:37.056: D/AndroidRuntime(3283): Shutting down VM
03-01 16:30:37.066: W/dalvikvm(3283): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
03-01 16:30:37.077: E/AndroidRuntime(3283): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-01 16:30:37.077: E/AndroidRuntime(3283): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application android.app.Application: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-01 16:30:37.077: E/AndroidRuntime(3283):     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:482)
03-01 16:30:37.077: E/AndroidRuntime(3283):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3909)
03-01 16:30:37.077: E/AndroidRuntime(3283):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:122)
03-01 16:30:37.077: E/AndroidRuntime(3283):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1184)
03-01 16:30:37.077: E/AndroidRuntime(3283):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-01 16:30:37.077: E/AndroidRuntime(3283):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-01 16:30:37.077: E/AndroidRuntime(3283):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
03-01 16:30:37.077: E/AndroidRuntime(3283):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-01 16:30:37.077: E/AndroidRuntime(3283):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-01 16:30:37.077: E/AndroidRuntime(3283):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-01 16:30:37.077: E/AndroidRuntime(3283):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-01 16:30:37.077: E/AndroidRuntime(3283):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-01 16:30:37.077: E/AndroidRuntime(3283): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-01 16:30:37.077: E/AndroidRuntime(3283):     at android.app.LoadedApk.initializeJavaContextClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:362)
03-01 16:30:37.077: E/AndroidRuntime(3283):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:305)
03-01 16:30:37.077: E/AndroidRuntime(3283):     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:474)
03-01 16:30:37.077: E/AndroidRuntime(3283):     ... 11 more
03-01 16:30:46.506: D/dalvikvm(3315): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 58K, 4% free 6909K/7171K, paused 52ms
03-01 16:30:46.517: I/dalvikvm-heap(3315): Grow heap (frag case) to 7.309MB for 488976-byte allocation
03-01 16:30:46.656: D/dalvikvm(3315): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 4% free 7385K/7687K, paused 4ms+3ms
03-01 16:30:47.206: D/gralloc_goldfish(3315): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
03-01 16:30:47.356: W/TextLayoutCache(3315): computeValuesWithHarfbuzz -- need to force to single run
03-01 16:30:52.366: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(3315): KeyEvent: ACTION_UP but key was not down.
03-01 16:30:52.366: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(3315):   in android.widget.EditText@41051d18
03-01 16:30:52.366: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(3315):   0: sent at 20208706000000, KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_TAB, scanCode=15, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=20208706, downTime=20208634, deviceId=0, source=0x101 }
03-01 16:30:53.956: I/LoginDetail(3315): Username jarnail@sassypuma.comPassword admin
03-01 16:30:54.036: D/dalvikvm(3315): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 72K, 3% free 7633K/7815K, paused 44ms
03-01 16:30:54.356: I/myLogin(3315): 1
03-01 16:30:54.726: D/dalvikvm(3315): GC_CONCURRENT freed 362K, 7% free 7694K/8199K, paused 29ms+6ms
03-01 16:30:55.026: I/AllFolders(3315): anyType{TreeData=anyType{ID=13002; FolderName=My Drive; ParentID=0; CreatedBy=1; }; TreeData=anyType{ID=13006; FolderName=Testing1; ParentID=0; CreatedBy=1; }; TreeData=anyType{ID=13007; FolderName=Testing123; ParentID=0; CreatedBy=1; }; }
03-01 16:30:55.506: D/dalvikvm(3315): GC_CONCURRENT freed 362K, 7% free 7767K/8263K, paused 24ms+7ms
03-01 16:30:55.886: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(3315): finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
03-01 16:30:57.246: I/FolderID(3315): 13002
03-01 16:30:57.246: I/User_ID(3315): 1
03-01 16:30:57.297: D/dalvikvm(3315): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 17K, 5% free 7880K/8263K, paused 48ms
03-01 16:30:57.297: I/dalvikvm-heap(3315): Grow heap (frag case) to 8.041MB for 262160-byte allocation
03-01 16:30:57.356: D/dalvikvm(3315): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 6% free 8133K/8583K, paused 52ms
```

Comment: Well yes, it's only taking the substring from character index 1 because that's explicitly what you've told it to... "The last substring" doesn't make sense without more context. I've posted an answer based solely on your example, but your question is far from clear.

Comment: I am sorry if my question is not clear, but thanks for your answer , I am trying to figure it out. thanks

Comment: problem is I am having diff type of images like .jpg, .png, .tif, I want if file is name.jpg then if subString is ".jpg" then particular image show in my custom image adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after getting answers from all..I think i have used StringTokenizer. And it Really works fine.

```
       StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(KEY_SUBFOLDERNAME, ".");
                String first_string = tokens.nextToken();
                File_Ext = tokens.nextToken();
                System.out.println("First_string : "+first_string);
                System.out.println("File_Ext : "+File_Ext);
```

Comment: We can sperate through . and then can get two values name ofthe file and extension...

Answer (score 6):

assume you have string like below

```
String Main_String =  "dsfdsf.jpg&&dfdfgfhfghgh.jpg&&dsfsdfgdgsdg.jpg"; 
String[] a = Main_String.split("&&");
for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
  System.out.println(""+a[i]);
  // you got all name here use what ever you want.
}
```

want only last name :

```
int last = Main_String.lastIndexOf('&&');
String laatname = Main_String.substring(last-2,Main_String.length());
```

Comment: I have different files like .png, .jpg, .doc, .pdf ext. so I want if file is .png then only .png image displays that I have in custom list adapter. if split is having .jpg value then jpg image displays in list adapter. so please suggest.

Comment: I am trying to use String[] str = KEY_SUBFOLDERNAME.split(".");
    str[2] = "jpg";
    
    System.out.println(str[1]);
    
    if(str[2] == "jpg"){
     FolderList item = new FolderList(JPGimages[0], Subfolderslist[2], Subfolderslist[1]);
     Subfolderdata.add(item);

Comment: no from web services. But I don't wnt to display the image, I only want to set adapter image

Comment: I don't have enough repo to chat in chatroom

Comment: response is fine, I have checked that using system print, but the only issue is split method.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you want everything from the final "." onwards, which would be something like:

```
int lastDot = text.lastIndexOf('.');
if (lastDot == -1) {
    // No dots - what do you want to do?
} else {
    String extension = text.substring(lastDot);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use this code to get your Answer
  like:`String Main_String =  dsfdsf.jpg`

```
Main_String.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);    //for`jpg`
```

`Main_String.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/"));`    `//for`.jpg
enjoy your code:)

Answer (score 2):

you can use this:

```
public static String getSubString(String mainString, String lastString, String startString) {
    String endString = "";
    int endIndex = mainString.indexOf(lastString);
    int startIndex = mainString.indexOf(startString);
    Log.d("message", "" + mainString.substring(startIndex, endIndex));
    endString = mainString.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
    return endString;
}
```

In this `mainString` is a Super string. Like "I_AmANDROID.Devloper" and `lastString` is a string like "." and `startString` is like "_". So this function returns "AmANDROID".

Answer (score 1):

If youn  have "tulips.jgp" with something like:

```
"tulips.jpg".split("\\.")
```

Will return you a array of strings withn  first item "tulips" and second "jpg"

Comment: but what if I am having different extensions like if image is .jpg/.png/.pdf then only that particular .jpg/.png/.pdf image displays in custom image adapter. I will go with further procedure but How to  satisfy if condition. if(subString == ".png"){} /not showing any result.

Answer (score 1):

As Jeen Broekstra,

What happen if the input like this?

```
String Input = " ,, Num1: 12, Num2: 23, ";
String n1 = getSubString(Input, ",", "Num1:");
```

So a little change is better I think:

```
public static String getSubString(String mainString, String startString, String lastString) {
    String endString = "";

    int startIndex = mainString.indexOf(startString);

    startIndex += startString.length();

    int endIndex = mainString.indexOf(lastString,startIndex );

    endString = mainString.substring(startIndex, endIndex);

    return endString;
}

String Input =" ,, Num1: 12, Num2: 23, ";
String n1=getSubString(Input,"Num1:",","); // n1=" 12"
String n2=getSubString(Input,"Num:",","); // n2=" 23"
```

Answer (score 0):

This requires you get the last four characters. This how I do it:

```
String fileName = "tulips.jpg";
String fileExt = fileName.substring(fileName.length() - 4);
Toast.makeText(this, "File extension is: "+ fileExt, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```